# How to check whether a twitter bootstrap popover is visible or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an element `$('#anElement')` with a potential popover attached, like

```
<div id="anElement" data-original-title="my title" data-trigger="manual" data-content="my content" rel="popover"></div>
```

I just would like to know how to check whether the popover is visible or not: how this can be accomplished with jQuery?

Comment: Please prodivde more mark-up.

Comment: @bram - under normal circumstances I would wholeheartedly agree with you. However in this case, the markup is the standard (twitter) bootstrap markup.

Comment: @Lix For people who are not familiar with Bootstrap it might be useful to have some sory of idea of what the mark up looks like

Comment: you're both right: Bram asked to have some more markup since the initial question was -at least- very short! on the other side, it's intended for people a bit familiar with the bootstrap.

Comment: You can also check using a condition `$('#anElement').next().hasClass('popover')`  which will return true if the popover is on.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If this functionality is not built into the framework you are using (it's no longer *twitter* bootstrap, just [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html)), then you'll have to inspect the HTML that is generated/modified to create this feature of bootstrap.

Take a look at the [popupver documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers). There is a button there that you can use to see it in action. This is a great place to inspect the HTML elements that are at work behind the scene.

Crack open your chrome developers tools or firebug (of firefox) and take a look at what it happening. It looks like there is simply a `<div>` being inserted after the button -

```
<div class="popover fade right in" style="... />
```

All you would have to do is check for the existence of that element. Depending on how your markup is written, you could use something like this -

```
if ($("#popoverTrigger").next('div.popover:visible').length){
  // popover is visible
}
```

`#popoverTrigger` is the element that triggered that popover to appear in the first place and as we noticed above, bootstrap simply appends the popover div after the element.

Comment: Yeah, maybe. Can't seem to debug it properly. Using IE9 debugger in IE8 mode, but can't see any modifications made to the DOM while popover is visible.

Comment: +1 I wanted to updated the tooltip while it was on display and this is really nice way to check if the tooltip is on display, hide, update and show. thanks

Comment: FYI if you copy/paste the demo from bootstrap, it won't work because they use the `data-container="body"` so the div is not with the `#popover-trigger` element.

Comment: @Marc - 3 year old code using a current library is bound to be problematic. I don't think that bootstrap is backwards compatible from 3 years ago. I don't actually remember which version I was using when I wrote this answer... It would definitely be a good idea to mention the specific version though...

Comment: There's no problem with your answer, it works with the latest version. You just need to remove the `data-container` or use another selector for the `next()`. I just wanted to mention it

Comment: @Marc oh.. I see I see.. Feel free to make the edit - I'm not using bootstrap anymore :-)

Comment: This will work in very particular case: when `div.popover` is the immediately following sibling of `"#popoverTrigger"`. This is very rare case depending on popover container option, which points on `body` by default.

Comment: Thanks! The approach of checking the visibility works great. Be careful on how popovers are triggered. Also set the popover options to trigger: 'manual'. Thanks again!

Answer (score 35):

There is no method implemented explicitly in the boostrap popover plugin so you need to find a way around that. Here's a hack that will return true or false wheter the plugin is visible or not.

```
var isVisible = $('#anElement').data('bs.popover').tip().hasClass('in');
console.log(isVisible); // true or false
```

It accesses the data stored by the popover plugin which is in fact a `Popover` object, calls the object's `tip()` method which is responsible for fetching the tip element, and then checks if the element returned has the class `in`, which is indicative that the popover attached to that element is visible.

---

You should also check if there is a popover attached to make sure you can call the `tip()` method:

```
if ($('#anElement').data('bs.popover') instanceof Popover) {
  // do your popover visibility check here
}
```

Comment: BOOTSTRAP 3 NOTE: In BS3 they changed it to bs.popover instead of popover. Example : `$('#anElement').data('bs.popover')`

Comment: Thank you for this solution but this still a hack. I run into this need because hide does not properly clean the HTML DOM while toggle does.

Answer (score 7):

In the current version of Bootstrap, you can check whether your element has `aria-describedby` set. The value of the attribute is the `id` of the actual popover.

So for instance, if you want to change the content of the visible popover, you can do:

```
var popoverId = $('#myElement').attr('aria-describedby');
$('#myElement').next(popoverid, '.popover-content').html('my new content');
```

Answer (score 3):

This checks if the given div is visible.

```
if ($('#div:visible').length > 0)
```

or

```
if ($('#div').is(':visible'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the most reliable option would be listening to shown/hidden events, as demonstrated below. This would eliminate the necessity of digging deep into the DOM that could be error prone.

```
var isMyPopoverVisible = false;//assuming popovers are hidden by default  

$("#myPopoverElement").on('shown.bs.popover',function(){
isMyPopoverVisible = true;
});

$("#myPopoverElement").on('hidden.bs.popover',function(){
isMyPopoverVisible = false;
});
```

These events seem to be triggered even if you hide/show/toggle the popover programmatically, without user interaction.

P. S. tested with BS3.

Answer (score 1):

This works with BS4:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.tooltip','#anElement', function() {
    $('#anElement').data('isvisible', true);
});

$(document).on('hidden.bs.tooltip','#anElement', function() {
    $('#anElement').data('isvisible', false);
});


if ($('#anElement').data('isvisible'))
{
    // popover is visible
    $('#tipUTAbiertas').tooltip('hide');
    $('#tipUTAbiertas').tooltip('show');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 5:

```js
const toggler = document.getElementById(togglerId);
const popover = bootstrap.Popover.getInstance(toggler);
const isShowing = popover && popover.tip && popover.tip.classList.contains('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple jQuery plugin to manage this. I've added few commented options to present different approaches of accessing objects and left uncommented that of my favor.

For current Bootstrap 4.0.0 you can take bundle with `Popover.js`: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js

```
// jQuery plugins
(function($)
{
    // Fired immiedately

    $.fn.isPopover = function (options)
    {
        // Is popover?
        // jQuery
        //var result = $(this).hasAttr("data-toggle");
        // Popover API
        var result = !!$(this).data('bs.popover');

        if (!options) return result;

        var $tip = this.popoverTip();

        if (result) switch (options)
        {
            case 'shown' :
                result = $tip.is(':visible');
                break;

            default:
                result = false;
        }

        return result;
    };    

    $.fn.popoverTip = function ()
    {
        // jQuery
        var tipId = '#' + this.attr('aria-describedby');
        return $(tipId);

        // Popover API by id
        //var tipId = this.data('bs.popover').tip.id;
        //return $(tipId);

        // Popover API by object
        //var tip = this.data('bs.popover').tip; // DOM element
        //return $(tip);
    };

    // Load indicator
    $.fn.loadIndicator = function (action)
    {
        var indicatorClass = 'loading';
        // Take parent if no container has been defined
        var $container = this.closest('.loading-container') || this.parent();

        switch (action)
        {
            case 'show' :
                $container.append($('<div>').addClass(indicatorClass));
                break;

            case 'hide' :
                $container.find('.' + indicatorClass).remove();
                break;
        }
    };
})(jQuery);

// Usage
// Assuming 'this' points to popover object (e.g. an anchor or a button)

// Check if popover tip is visible
var isVisible = $(this).isPopover('shown');

// Hide all popovers except this
if (!isVisible) $('[data-toggle="popover"]').not(this).popover('hide');

// Show load indicator inside tip on 'shown' event while loading an iframe content
$(this).on('shown.bs.popover', function ()
{
    $(this).popoverTip().find('iframe').loadIndicator('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a way to check the state with Vanilla JS.

```
document.getElementById("popover-dashboard").nextElementSibling.classList.contains('popover');
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a popover with boostrap 4, tip() doesn't seem to be a function anymore. This is one way to check if a popover is enabled, basically if it has been clicked and is active:

```
if ($('#element').data('bs.popover')._activeTrigger.click == true){
...do something
}
```

Comment: Underscore properties are internal implementation details. They are to be treated as such and may change at any time, meaning your little code snippet can (read: will) randomly break at some point in the future with no warning (like a changelog or API deprecation warning).