# How to do auto tooltip validation msg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Here I created sample file for validation, which is working fine...

But My requirement is I need to do some modification on that while validating. Error message need to show in auto tooltip. It needs to be shown automatically when there is error and hide automatically once error cleared. Until error clear popup need to be stay.

[image]

If it is possible without jquery or else with jquery also fine.

[image]

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['UserValidation']);

myappCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.formAllGood = function () {
        return ($scope.usernameGood && $scope.passwordGood && $scope.passwordCGood)
    }
        
}

angular.module('UserValidation', []).directive('validUsername', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                // Any way to read the results of a "required" angular validator here?
                var isBlank = viewValue === ''
                var invalidChars = !isBlank && !/^[A-z0-9]+$/.test(viewValue)
                var invalidLen = !isBlank && !invalidChars && (viewValue.length < 5 || viewValue.length > 20)
                ctrl.$setValidity('isBlank', !isBlank)
                ctrl.$setValidity('invalidChars', !invalidChars)
                ctrl.$setValidity('invalidLen', !invalidLen)
                scope.usernameGood = !isBlank && !invalidChars && !invalidLen

            })
        }
    }
}).directive('validPassword', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                var isBlank = viewValue === ''
                var invalidLen = !isBlank && (viewValue.length < 8 || viewValue.length > 20)
                var isWeak = !isBlank && !invalidLen && !/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])/.test(viewValue)
                ctrl.$setValidity('isBlank', !isBlank)
                ctrl.$setValidity('isWeak', !isWeak)
                ctrl.$setValidity('invalidLen', !invalidLen)
                scope.passwordGood = !isBlank && !isWeak && !invalidLen

            })
        }
    }
}).directive('validPasswordC', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue, $scope) {
                var isBlank = viewValue === ''
                var noMatch = viewValue != scope.myform.password.$viewValue
                ctrl.$setValidity('isBlank', !isBlank)
                ctrl.$setValidity('noMatch', !noMatch)
                scope.passwordCGood = !isBlank && !noMatch
            })
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <form  name="myform" class="form form-horizontal" ng-controller="myappCtrl" novalidate>
    <legend>Angular User Validation with Bootstrap Decorations</legend>
    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error:!myform.username.$valid}">
        <label for="inputUsername" class="control-label">Username:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputUsername" name="username" ng-model="username" valid-username />
            <div class="help-inline">
                <span ng-show="!!myform.username.$error.isBlank">Username Required.</span>
    <span ng-show="!!myform.username.$error.invalidChars">Username must contain letters &amp; spaces only.</span>
                <span ng-show="!!myform.username.$error.invalidLen">Username must be 5-20 characters.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error:!myform.password.$valid}">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Password:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputPassword" name="password" ng-model="password" valid-password />
            <div class="help-inline">
                <span ng-show="!!myform.password.$error.isBlank">Password Required.</span>
                <span ng-show="!!myform.password.$error.isWeak">Must contain one upper &amp; lower case letter and a non-letter (number or symbol.)</span> 
                <span ng-show="!!myform.password.$error.invalidLen">Must be 8-20 characters.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error:!myform.password_c.$valid}">
        <label for="password_c" class="control-label">Confirm Password:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="password_c" name="password_c" ng-model="password_c" valid-password-c />
            <div class="help-inline"> 
                <span ng-show="!!myform.password_c.$error.isBlank">Confirmation Required.</span>
                <span ng-show="!!myform.password_c.$error.noMatch">Passwords don't match.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions" ng-show="formAllGood()">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
    </div>
    </form></div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is the issue? You code seems to work fine

Comment: I need the validation error msg need to be show as a auto popup...Once Error clear auto hide popup...

Comment: for reference see the image

Comment: Are you looking for something like "This field is required" in following image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VBxDy.jpg ? If yes, you can look into `tooltip`.

Comment: yeah, popup need to come automatically while keypress

Comment: tooltip msg only without mouse hover and it need stay constant until clear error

Comment: You can look into [Bootstrap - Pop overs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) . Check following [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattdlockyer/C5GBU/2/)

Comment: Whay you mean with: `If it is possible without jquery or else with jquery also fine. `

Comment: So much code for such a simple thing. `<input type="______" required />`

Comment: @Rajesh pop over is fine is it possible to popover without click even.. using keypress?

Comment: @Luis Auto tooltip need to show with or without using jquery..

Comment: @ Niet the Dark Absol  if u put like that while submit that time only one field it will show that one also one by one right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to *show/hide* popover on any event. Following code depicts a validate function for numbers using popover.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VUZhL/2229/).

```js
function validate(el) {
  var regex = /^\d+$/g;
  var valid = regex.test(el.value);
  if (!valid) {
    
    // Check if popover is already visible to handle flicker effect.
    if ($("#txtInput").next('div.popover').length == 0) {
      
      $('#txtInput').popover({
        placement: 'bottom',
        content: 'This is not a valid entry'
      }).popover('show');
      
    }
  } else {
    $('#txtInput').popover('hide');
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="txtInput" onkeyup="validate(this)">
```

#### References:

- [Check visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442749/how-to-check-whether-a-twitter-bootstrap-popover-is-visible-or-not)
- [Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers).

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to use **[Parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/)**

**Why Parsley :**

- Validation Event can be customized  (onsubmit , onkeyup , or any other event )
- Validation Style can be customized
- Validation message will automatically disappear , once input satisfies conditions

Check their **[examples](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples.html)**

Comment: it is possible to show auto tooltip? while entering value it need to be show, once input satisfied it need to hide...

Comment: any sample in jsfiddle? or can u able post some sample here?